# How do I stop DVD player from autoplaying?

Tags: optical-drive, dvd

When I insert a movie DVD into my USB superdrive, the DVD player starts.  I want it to stop doing that.

I've tried the following to disable this behaviour:

- System Preferences -> CDs & DVDs -> When you insert a video DVD: set to Ignore (actually moved all of them to Ignore)
- DVD player -> Preferences -> unchecked "Start playing disc" for when DVD player opens and when a disc is inserted.

Neither of these made a difference; insert the disc and the DVD player still starts playing it. Any other options?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might have more success using [RCDefaultApp](http://www.rubicode.com/Software/RCDefaultApp/) (freeware, old but still functional) if only because it shows a few more choices of precisely what to ignore.

[image]

Comment: That was really helpful! Seemed to make the difference. Thank you.

Comment: Does not work anymore in Big Sur / SwiftDefaultApps (no Media tab) https://github.com/Lord-Kamina/SwiftDefaultApps, Any other solutions?